# Use Record Class with select new spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, record

Is it possible to use **record** as return type with `select new`  syntax in spring data jpa query ?

Something like this:

```
@query("select new path-to-my-record.MyRecord(...)
List<MyRecord> myQuery(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, starting from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.4` you can use Java records within JPQL queries. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-java-records for use-cases.

Example:

```java
// your entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
    
    // constructors, getters, setters
}

// corresponding record
public record BookRecord(Long id, String title, String author, String isbn) {}

// repository. You can use both named queries and `@Query` annotation
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

  List<BookRecord> findBookByAuthor(String author);

  @Query("SELECT new com.full.package.name.BookRecord(b.id, b.title, b.author, b.isbn) FROM Book b WHERE b.id = :id")
  BookRecord findBookById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Comment: If you could paste the code here, I will mark your answer as the accepted one ^^

Comment: @AmirChoubani done